# Что даёт это вычисление в результате?

Tags: математика

```
arr = [1,2,3]

result = sum(arr)/(count(arr)*count(arr)) = 0,667
```

Что дает это вычисление, кто-нибудь в курсе?
Что такое `0,667`?

Comment: С математикой совсем плохо? 6/9=0.667

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Среднее, деленное на количество элементов.

Может пригодиться, например, при вычислении среднеквадратичного отклонения в один проход или при вычислениях по методу наименьших квадратов...

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Я разбираюсь вот в этом https://github.com/adriannuta/SphinxAutocompleteExample/blob/master/functions.php#L29. Пока не могу понять зачем это тут применяют :) Может Вы поймёте. Вкратце скажу, что это связано с результатом работы  поисковой системы.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sum = 1+2+3 = 6
Count * Count = 3*3 = 9
6/9 = 0.667
```